# What's the correct way to generate a .pom file from my pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I've been learning how to publish a Java library to jcenter. jcenter/bintray wants me to upload the following artifacts:

1. Binaries: `{groupId}/{artifactId}-{version}.jar`
2. Source: `{groupId}/{artifactId}-{version}-sources.jar`
3. (Optionally) Javadoc: `{groupId}/{artifactId}-{version}-javadoc.jar`
4. POM: `{groupId}/{artifactId}-{version}.pom`

I can generate the first three no problem (binaries with a standard `mvn package` and sources and javadoc using the plugins described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)).

Currently I'm just manually copying my `pom.xml` to `{groupId}/{artifactId}-{version}.pom` and that works fine, but it smells. I'm sure there must be an automated Maven way of doing this but I can't find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can upload your Maven project directly to [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) just by adding some code to your pom.xml and then running the appropriate `mvn` command**:

First add a distribution section to your maven and specify the URL from which to distribute your project:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
      <id>bintray-repo-maven-example</id>
      <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/tamarjfrog/maven-repo/maven-example/;publish=1</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In order to work with Bintray you need to provide your Bintray username and API Key as upload credentials in the username and password tags of your Maven settings.xml file. The API Key can be found when editing your Bintray profile page:

```
<server>
  <id>bintray-repo-maven-example</id>
  <username>tamarjfrog</username>
  <password>***my-top-secret-api-key***</password>
</server>
```

the you just run this simple command:

> mvn deploy

The project will be built, uploaded to the the Bintray repository target URL you provided, and published. For more information take a look [here](https://blog.bintray.com/2015/09/17/publishing-your-maven-project-to-bintray/).

Answer (score 0):

`mvn deploy` should automatically push your pom